# pandas: how to check if a column value is in other columns in the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame in the following format:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
A    A    B    Z    X
B    A    Z    Z    X
A    A    C    Z    X
C    A    C    D    X
D    A    B    D    X
```

How can I filter the rows where the value in `col1` is in `col2`, `col3` or `col4` (disregarding `col5`)?

I tried among other things:

```
df = df[df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']].isin(['col1'])]
```

but get an empty data frame.

The expected output would be:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
A    A    B    Z    X
A    A    C    Z    X
C    A    C    D    X
D    A    B    D    X
```

Comment: can you please post expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if **`any`** of the values are equal (**`eq`**) the value in column 1. [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) supports an axis argument.

```
m = df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']].eq(df['col1'], axis=0).any(1)
df[m]

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0    A    A    B    Z    X
2    A    A    C    Z    X
3    C    A    C    D    X
4    D    A    B    D    X
```

Answer (score 4):

[Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) is an option to get equality row-wise then check if any `True` on axis 1 with [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'C', 4: 'D'},
    'col2': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A'},
    'col3': {0: 'B', 1: 'Z', 2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'B'},
    'col4': {0: 'Z', 1: 'Z', 2: 'Z', 3: 'D', 4: 'D'},
    'col5': {0: 'X', 1: 'X', 2: 'X', 3: 'X', 4: 'X'}
})

m = (df['col1'].values[:, None] == df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']].values).any(1)

filtered = df[m]
print(filtered)
```

`filtered`:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0    A    A    B    Z    X
2    A    A    C    Z    X
3    C    A    C    D    X
4    D    A    B    D    X
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix your code by adding `any`

```
df = df[df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']].isin(df['col1']).any(1)]
df
Out[135]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0    A    A    B    Z    X
2    A    A    C    Z    X
3    C    A    C    D    X
4    D    A    B    D    X
```